# Finding missing comic chapter by Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have an example of a comic collection database data frame as follow:

```
  title chapter
0   A     1
1   A     2
2   A     3
3   A     5
4   B     2
5   B     4
6   B     7
7   C     3
8   C     1
```

assuming that the latest chapter available for each title is available at the table above, how to identify the missing chapter for each title with python code?

```
 title chapter
0   A     4
1   B     1
2   B     3
3   B     5
4   B     6
5   C     2
```

The output of the code is supposed to be able to produce the missing chapters such as the table above (it does not have to be a table, as long as it can find the missing chapter from a comic collection data frame. Thank you for any input and answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you provide code of your attempts? YOu should have a look at python sets, which allow differences.

Comment: I have tried to search for the answer myself for finding missing collections within dictionary; however, none turned up. I also managed to be able to find missing numbers within sequence by using difference() such as
`start = lst[0]` 
`end = lst[-1]` 
`print(sorted(set(range(start, end + 1)).difference(lst)))`

but when I tried to apply it to the dictionary, I got confused :(

Comment: @AudiChandra In general, I like your question and cannot follow the harsh downvoting. It indeed is a problem of certain complexity and you stated well what you want to achieve. What is missing for me is a specification of your data type (as I added it in my answer `DataFrame({"title": ["A"] * 4 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 2, "chapter": [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1]})`) and a few notes on your attempts. Hope you consider your first question as good experience and a first step to your personal shining Stackoverflow journey! :)

Comment: Thank you @matheburg, it downvoted because I published the unfinished post when I tried to see the result and during the time people see when I edit it, that is when they downvoted it :(. Btw thank you for the answer and if I can ask, what do you mean by the data type?, is it the data type of each column or like the data frame?

Comment: @AudiChandra By "missing [...] data type", I refer to the fact you are lacking a specification of the `type` of your input data. We can just guess by the format of the output that this is a Pandas `DataFrame`. Ideally, I would have expected that you provide a piece of code that defines the test data object for us (as I did with `comic_book_collection = ...`).

Comment: @matheburg thank you for the answer, in the future I will follow the formats you specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Welcome on stackoverflow! I guess you are working with a pandas `DataFrame`. Next time, provide all relevant details on data format and existing code in your question, please.

As your use case doesn't sound runtime critical, you should go for a simple algorithm you easily understand. This gives you confidence on the correctness. One proposal:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

def find_missing_chapters(comic_book_collection):
    missing_chapters = {}
    max_found = {}
    for _, row in comic_book_collection.T.iteritems():
        title = row["title"]
        chapter = row["chapter"]
        if title not in missing_chapters:
            missing_chapters.update({title: list(range(1, chapter))})
            max_found.update({title: chapter})
        else:
            if max_found[title] < chapter:
                missing_chapters[title] += list(range(max_found[title] + 1, chapter))
                max_found[title] = chapter
            else:  # if uniqueness of items in input is not guaranteed, you may want to
                   # write here: `elif chapter in missing_chapters[title]:` instead
                missing_chapters[title].remove(chapter)
    return missing_chapters


comic_book_collection = DataFrame(
    {"title": ["A"] * 4 + ["B"] * 3 + ["C"] * 2, "chapter": [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1]})
print(find_missing_chapters(comic_book_collection))
```

Output:

```
{'A': [4], 'B': [1, 3, 5, 6], 'C': [2]}
```